# Software or applet to check if a server is up

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a software which can tell me if a server is up or down.

Typically I need that the software call a specific url every 2 seconds and check the content of the response.

If content match, green indicator, if not red indicator.

Simple, does it exist?

Comment: You might buil a script which uses curl to output the response to stdout and check the content with bash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. I only know of Conky though, which *can* be a little on the technical side.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMKqEVMFKFY

In the description, he shows his coding to get Conky to show the server status of whatever server you wish.

An explanation to help you get started with Conky can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky

Conky can also monitor your CPU, RAM, Weather of your area, be a clock, etc. It is a really great tool to have and learn!